# HTML Page search

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very long html file (20K+ lines) and I want to have a search that will find the search term and then scroll to the `li class="page" data-name="XX"`. If more than one instance of the term is found we need a "next" result button.

Here is an excerpt from my HTML file I want to search:

```
  <li class="page" data-name="11">
<div class="pageResizer" style="width:640px;height:960px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="item690" class="pageItem" alt="Rectangle">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="item728" class="pageItem" alt="Rectangle">&nbsp;</div><button class="pageItem" alt="Home" id="item1426" data-id="1426" onclick="nav.to(5);">&nbsp;</button><button class="pageItem" alt="prevBtn" id="item1423" data-id="1423" onclick="nav.back(this);">&nbsp;</button><button class="pageItem" alt="nextBtn" id="item2550" data-id="2550" onclick="nav.next(this);">&nbsp;</button><img src="assets/images/blank.gif" class="pageItem" alt="Rectangle" style="left:491px;top:11px;" data-src="assets/images/item_2757.png"/>
<div id="item2788" class="pageItem singleline" alt="Lafayette Chamber">
  <p class="autoParaStyle1">Lafayette Chamber</p>
</div><button class="pageItem" alt="Share" id="item3136" data-id="3136">&nbsp;</button>
<a href="javascript:nav.to(2);"><button class="pageItem" alt="Help" id="item2977" data-id="2977" onclick="nav.to(2);">&nbsp;</button>
</a><img src="assets/images/blank.gif" class="pageItem" alt="Rectangle" style="left:1px;top:66px;" data-src="assets/images/item_4899.jpg"/><img src="assets/images/blank.gif" class="pageItem" alt="Rectangle" style="left:1px;top:707px;" data-src="assets/images/item_4901.jpg"/>
<div id="item4906" class="pageItem singleline" alt="lafayETTE ">
  <p class="autoParaStyle13">lafayETTE<br />
  </p>
</div>
<div id="item4937" class="pageItem singleline" alt="HISTORY">
  <p class="autoParaStyle14">HISTORY</p>
</div>
<div id="item4982" class="pageItem" alt=" little more than a century ago, the first pioneers trickled into this region after a long journey across the Great P...">
  <p class="Article-Body"> <span class="autoCharStyle5">little more than a century ago, the first pioneers trickled into this region after a long journey across the Great Plains.  The gold rush attracted more and more adventurous fortune seekers who were closely followed by other settlers.  The honeymoon of Lafayette and Mary E. Miller was spent crossing the plains and arriving in the Boulder region.  In 1863, they started farming the Burlington (Longmont) area and soon moved south and settled in the present site of Lafayette.  Lafayette Miller was an industrious man and besides farming, he operated the stage stop and ran several meat markets.  His sudden death in 1878 left Mary Miller with six small children to raise.  She did this and more…she raised a town!<br /></span>      </p>
  <p class="autoParaStyle8"><br /></p>
</div>
<div id="item27143" class="pageItem singleline" alt="A">
  <p class="autoParaStyle15">A</p>
</div>
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<script>
function search() {

var name = document.getElementById("searchForm").elements["searchItem"].value;
var pattern = name.toLowerCase();
var targetId = "";

var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("page");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var para = divs[i].getElementsByTagName("p");
  var index = para[0].innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern);
  if (index != -1) {
     targetId = divs[i].parentNode.id;
     document.getElementById(targetId).scrollIntoView();
     break;
  }
}  
}
</script>

<form id="searchForm" action="javascript:search();">
<div class="input-group">
  <button id="go"  type="button" 
          onclick="document.getElementById('searchForm').submit(); return false;">
  Search</button>
  <input type="text" id="searchItem" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" cols="50" rows="2">
</div>
</form>
```

Not sure what I need to do to my code to make this work and don't have a clue how to make a "next result" button.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <form id="searchForm" action="javascript:search();" class="form">
    <button id="nextButton" onclick="nextItem()" type="button" class="make-invisible">NEXT</button>
    <div class="input-group">
      <button id="go">Search</button>
      <input type="text" id="searchItem" name="searchItem" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" cols="50" rows="2">
    </div>
  </form>
  <ul>
    <li class="page" data-name="foo">Has data-name = foo</li>
    <li class="page" data-name="foo">Has data-name = foo</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var selectedItems;
var currentlySelectedItem;
var makeInvisibleClassName = "make-invisible";
var nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextButton");

function search() {
  makeInvisible();
  var searchPhrase = document.querySelector("#searchItem").value;
  selectedItems = document.querySelectorAll(".page[data-name='" + searchPhrase + "']");
  if (selectedItems.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  if (selectedItems.length > 1) {
    makeVisible();
  }
  currentlySelectedItem = 0;
  nextItem();
}

function nextItem() {
  selectedItems[currentlySelectedItem].scrollIntoView();
  currentlySelectedItem++;
  if (currentlySelectedItem >= selectedItems.length) {
    currentlySelectedItem = 0;
  }
}

//////////
function makeInvisible() {
  nextButton.classList.add(makeInvisibleClassName);
}

function makeVisible() {
  nextButton.classList.remove(makeInvisibleClassName);
}
```

CSS:

```
.form {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#nextButton {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.make-invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

Here is the working [Demo](https://codepen.io/Humberd/pen/dXqdmm)

Ok, let me explain what I did here.
When you have a form you don't actually need to this:

```
<button id="go" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('searchForm').submit(); return false;">
```

Instead you can go very simple:

```
<button id="go">Search</button>
```

The default button type in a form is `type="submit"` which automatically triggers the event specified in the action attribute.

The next thing is the NEXT button. I hard-coded it and in order to show it and hide it, I will add or remove class `make-invisible`. Notice the button is invisible at the beginning. It also has a click event which will trigger `nextItem()`

```
<button id="nextButton" onclick="nextItem()" type="button" class="make-invisible">NEXT</button>
```

I also made 2 global variables: `selectedItems`, which will store the array of selected items and `currentlySelectedItem` that has the index of currently scrolled to item.

The `search()` function gets all elements that has the class name `page` and has attribute `data-name` with specified word. Then it checks if there is more then one result. If so, it makes the button visible.

The `nextItem()` function scrolls into selected element, and raises index by one. If the index value if bigger then there is matching elements, it will start a loop.

Comment: I must apologize for not making myself clear with you. This website has 500+ "pages". One of those pages was what I used as my example html file. Here is an example of what I am looking for: Visitor types in a search term and taps "Search". The code finds the search term and "scrollToView" to that "page". Then the "Next" button is displayed to navigate the visitor to the next page with that key word. When I put your code in my page, the search box was displayed, but when a term was entered and search tapped, then nothing happens. Sorry if I am just being thick.